# How do I get Facebook to clear it's object cache?

Tags: embed, vimeo

I'm trying to get a vimeo video to properly embed, however the facebook object debugging tool will not pull in the right values.  The scraping shows the main vimeo page and not the video page.  I compared the two sources and they don't match at all.

So my question is, how can I force Facebook to clear it's cache?  It's quite clearly having issues, I check the vimeo tags and everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug will clear the embed cache.